Electronic speed controller - how to know what frequency for servo pulses? Why use 50 Hz?
I was doing a Raspberry Pi project controlling a BLDC motor with an BLHeli32 ESC.
I sent servo pulses with maximum width 2 ms and minimum width 1 ms. The frequency I sent these pulses at is 50 Hz. This seems to be recommended across different ESCs in general.
From Wikipedia: "The ESC generally accepts a nominal 50 Hz PWM servo input signal whose pulse width varies from 1 ms to 2 ms."
What would happen if I used a different frequency but kept the same pulsewidths? How does the frequency impact the ESC behavior?

We can't know how different ESCs respond timings that are out of the usual rannge.

Did you look up the operational conditions of the ESC? What do they say? -- Are you trying to operate the ESC outside its limits? If, so, please [edit] your question to explain why. -- Whatever works inside the ESC, anything can happen, from no observable effect to all kinds of erroneous behaviour. Just try it, but don't blame us in case of disasters. :-D

50 Hz pulse repetition frequency (PRF) for servoes is the 'industry standard'.
For small deviations from that (the key word is 'nominal'), any servo or ESC should be able to cope, and continue to provide an output as a function of the pulse high time. This is not PWM, the duty cycle is not the controlling factor here.
How big is a 'small' deviation? You would expect at least a few percent. You would not want your servoes to stop operating for a tiny error in PRF, even if inaccurate RC oscillators were used for the timebase.
I used a small servo recently that quoted 20 Hz to 100 Hz PRF in the data sheet. I found that it stopped responding below 10 Hz. Your ESC should also have a data sheet that specifies a valid PRF range. Each servo or ESC implementation could have a different valid range. Test yours on the bench before you test it in the air.
There's no fundamental reason why a PRF as high as 500 Hz (1/max pulse on time) should not be used. However, practical circuit design will mean some recovery time between pulses, and an MCU solution will probably have a 'if PRF > some_limit then something_has_gone_wrong' test in it somewhere. There's no fundamental reason why the PRF can't go down to zero. However, zero PRF is not distinguishable from 'broken or misbehaving control path', and failing safe at some low frequency seems a good plan.

In the beginning of "PWM" controlled servos back in the 70s there are no microcontrollers in use. Instead a simple digital logic used the difference between the input pulse and the local reference pulse to drive the motor. The difference was dead-zone filtered, prolonged, and directly used to control an H bridge. This would not work if the PRF deviates more than a few percent. However, these times are gone.
